# Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir (Errno::EACCES) after installing RVM RUBY AND SHOPIFY-CLI

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify, rvm

I have been stranded with this 5 hours today, and no online answers seem to exist for my problem....

I just installed .rvm and ruby + gem in order to start as a Shopify Developer. As a installed shopify-cli, and consequently log `shopify version`, I get this:

roger.rangel@Rogers-MacBook-Pro Current % shopify version
/Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/roger.rangel/.config/shopify (Errno::EACCES) from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:253:in` fu_mkdir'
from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:231:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p' from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:229:in` reverse_each'
from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:229:in `block in mkdir_p' from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:211:in` each'
from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p' from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.3.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/config.rb:128:in` write_config'
from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.3.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/config.rb:55:in `set' from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.3.0/lib/shopify-cli/context.rb:607:in` update_time_of_last_check'
from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.3.0/lib/shopify-cli/context.rb:560:in `new_version' from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.3.0/lib/shopify-cli/core/entry_point.rb:13:in` call'
from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.3.0/bin/shopify:33:in `block in <main>' from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.3.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:75:in` handle_abort'
from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.3.0/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:21:in `call' from /Users/roger.rangel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.3.0/bin/shopify:32:in` '

How can I just get rid of this problem???? I am new to web development :(

Comment: What does running in the terminal `stat /Users/roger.rangel/.config/shopify` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sometimes happens when you have run some install command as root. That is, if you have for instance installed `rvm` using `sudo` for some command - which has put the ownership of a directory to the `root` user of your computer (remember that MacOS is essentially UNIX with a nice UI).

To solve it, in your terminal you have to run

```sh
sudo chown -R roger.rangel: /Users/roger.rangel/.config
```

Another possibility is that you just don't have that directory, in that case, again in your terminal

```sh
mkdir /Users/roger.rangel/.config
```